# cudaMemcpy doesn't work in 64 bits

Tags: cuda, 32bit-64bit

I made a very simple CUDA kernel which populates an array of 100 elements with f[i]=i (and checked using assert in another kernel that it had indeed done so).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<assert.h>

//definizione di gpuErrchk    

__global__ void setToItself(int* vect){
    vect[threadIdx.x] = threadIdx.x;
}

int main(){

int* a_d;

gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc(&a_d, 100 * sizeof(int)) );

setToItself<<<1,100>>>(a_d);

gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
```

I then copy the array back to the host for displaying using

```
int* a_h[100];

gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(a_h, a_d, 100*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    printf("%d %d\n",i, a_h[i]);

system("PAUSE");
}
```

When I compile it in 32 bit it works fine, but in 64 bits i get

```
f[0]=0
f[1]=2
f[2]=4
...
```

and the second half of the array is undefined.

I tried to change the compute_ and sm_ back from 35 to 20 as was default on 32 bits, but to no avail.

I tried adding error checking everywhere, but I got no output, meaning all functions returned success.

I searched, but there doesn't seem to be particular problems associated with 64 bit transition. What is this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
int* a_h[100];
```

It should be:

```
int a_h[100];
```

You want an array of 100 `int` *values*.  Not an array of 100 `int` *pointers*.  `int` *values* don't change their size between 32 and 64 bits.  `int` *pointers* do change their size.

Comment: It is amazing how it even managed to compile before :/ Thank you!

Comment: So... C just let me write and read integer values to and from a pointer type without even raising an eyebrow. *shivers*

Comment: @Francesco: Let's not go blaming this on the compiler, shall we. There is nothing syntactically wrong with the code, nor is there anything invalid in memory access or casting within the code. If anything in that bothers you, I recommend learning Python....

Comment: @talonmies it does seem to me that integer and pointer are logically very different things, but maybe it's just me.

Comment: @buttifulbuttefly stronger how?

Comment: @Francesco: on the architectures in question, an `int` is a 4 byte word representing a signed integer, and a `void *` is either a 4 or 8 byte word representing unsigned integers. You inadvertently copied 100 4 byte words into the first half of an array sized to hold 100 8 byte words and then printed those 100 8 byte words out as 4 byte words. All of which is perfectly valid. And then came here to complain that a CUDA API didn't work, when the true culprit was not understanding what you had done.

Comment: @Francesco: And, having just compiled your code with gcc, I got this compiler warning: `warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int*’`. So either you need a better compiler, or you ignored a compiler warning as well

Comment: @talonmies alas now I have to use VisualStudio, and even looking for it, I don't see any such warning. Although it is very possible I just don't know where to look. I'll study better how that thing works.